# Компиляция програм через notepad++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, компиляция, компилятор

Кто знает как настроить Notepad++ с компилятором MS VC++, чтобы можно было из под блокнота компилировать ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Идея в том, чтобы привязать некоторый батч к `cl.exe` *(компилятору `Microsoft Visual C++`).* Варианты того, как это можно сделать, посмотрите [**тут.**](https://web.archive.org/web/20120605154512/https://forums.anandtech.com/showthread.php?t=85537)